# kmail's sending accounts gone

Tags: upgrade, kde, kmail

After upgrading to KDE4.5, my kmail sending accounts are gone. I can see them in the .kmailrc file, but they don't show up in the settings dialog.

I think this may have something to do with Akonadi.

How can I get them back without have to retype them in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akonadi-based Kontact suite (Kmail included) is not released alongside KDE SC 4.5 - it will be later this year.

If you have installed the new (beta) version of Kmail 2, I'd suggest you to revert to the old one. The good thing is that Kmail 2 doesn't alter the data from kmailrc but converts it and uses kmail2rc, so the old one should work without a glitch.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I've seen an SQL and Akonadi error a couple times. I also lost all my journal data for some reason. Well, it's in the backup, but KDE4.5 didn't seem to like where it is. I think it may be because of this new way of managing resources. Too bad all those upgrade scripts will be of no use because everyone will have already upgraded because the distros do.

Comment: Yes, distros spoiled quite a few things in KDE4.x till now. There will always be workarounds - just check forums.kde.org often ;)